# Android load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found.

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found.
anybody know how to solve this ? i am trying to implement ViewPager in android studio but it gives me this error when it calls CustomAdapter which extends PagerAdapter

Comment: That's a very odd error message to encounter unless you are using NDK code of your own - Mali is a gpu functional block used in a lot of mobile SoCs but should not normally be exposed to an Android app.  Can you try on a different device or emulator?  It is also possible that this message is a routine and unimportant result of a device being set up to try things in multiple ways only some of which work.  So the real error may be different.  Please post the actual stack trace leading to a hard failure of your program.

Answer (score 0):

It is a device error mostly related to the core hardware of the device . But it won't stop execution of program

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's how I resolved:

I was making a new helper class which use `SQLite`. I tested inserting and row count, everything went well. I then made some changes in my code and used a Context object before initialising and started getting the error, no solution anywhere. Then I initialised the object and the problem was resolved. So this is to help future readers:

- Check if the same error occurs after commenting recent codes
- As I found the problem is with a `Context` object, please check your context objects and then other objects

If nothing can solve your problem please tell me to remove this answer as it may create future confusions.